# Convert serial chain of promise returning functions to async/await

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to translate a code from *Promise returning* one to *async/await*. My example code has 2 classes.

[Example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBBCBPAdsaBvAsAFDQnQAOATgJYBuYS80kWOAZgIwAUmAXE5ugCUeIqTHQI8JLCoBbeAHsArkk6dhAXgB8I4uP3AFmCApDwAdCAUBzTgCI0LaOz53oAamiZBAblH7xCiklCkwvPz19AF8AGmcAVgAGRN9-EiiiNPJqOgYmDGxoVgAmbj4wAWECSPFJaTlFFTVNHWqA8UNjUwsrWwcCnGLXDy9UmvagpBCwzAj22OdklLnSDMIssiUAIxAqHGZC1nVddrAAdzAqJGgkAAsqCHMOTnZBLLFzy%20u7h6fS4rGYjWayIoEgMAQyAAChQFLIHow2qRKLR6Ixnrx%20EITgFJtMvPAztAYXCEWogiYQDR4HEggAreDAJAtHHtEh1GTyZSqY7aVlssQU0zU7iAgUdIyUno2ewk%20GSZzDTzeFYChbsJLLd6rMXpTI1FG5dGlTEVbFI-R40IEolysmcIVUmnQemM5nQPkWtkchrc5oe1ragWOkUqoNszpSywyux2hUuaBuZW6tnqpYpoEpkEG7a7fYDIrHL0fC5XG73R7PV6q8SfMs-Sv-LNEbPcQlwRCoAbqQRPdQRNtEyFIOPwHt9sZAA)

First one, `TestAsync`, functions are `async`. This class prints 2 first, then 1. Which means they run parallel and doesn't wait for the first one to finish.

```
class TestAsync {
    private async f1(n: any) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Async 1: " + n);
            return n;
        }, 1500);
    }

    private async f2(n: any) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Async 2: " + n);
            return n;
        }, 1000);
    }

    public async f() {
        await this.f1(1)
        await this.f2(2);
    }
}
```

In the second one, `TestPromise`, functions return Promises without async fucntions. This class prints 1 first, then 2. That's what I expected (waiting for the first one to finish) also the `TestAsync` should do.

```
class TestPromise {
    private f1(n: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(n);
                console.log("Promise 1: " + n);
            }, 1500);
        });
    }

    private f2(n: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(n);
                console.log("Promise 2: " + n);
            }, 1000);
        });
    }

    public async f() {
        await this.f1(1);
        await this.f2(2);
    }
}
```

How can I make `TestAsync` function to behave like `TestPromise`?

Comment: What do you think “await” waits for?

Comment: Since setTimeout does not create a promise, if you want to use async/await with it, you must create that promise yourself. So the second piece of code (or some minor variant of it) is the way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: As far as I can understand, if we make a function async it automatically returns a Promise without declaring that explicitly.

Comment: It's true that async functions return promises, but if the code in the async function doesn't `await` anything, that promise is going to resolve right away.

Comment: So, just assuming that setTimeout() returns a promise, TestAsync may also work. In the functions f1() and f2() we can say "await setTimeout()" and is it going to work like TestPromise ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. If you'd like to make a helper function to set a timeout and return a promise, that would look something like: `const delay = (duration) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));`. So then you could do `await delay(1000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async/await are mostly syntactic sugar around promises. So when dealing with APIs that are not marked as async or returning a promise - such as setTimeout in your example -, they'll still need to be converted into promises.

In your TestAsync example, the functions don't return anything so `await` doesn't have anything to wait for.

You might want to run callback-based functions through promisify or use the new timers promise API in Node.js:
https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api
Then they can be used in conjunction with `await`.

Comment: Thanks for the package recommendation, but I just used these setTimeout() functions for the sake of the example. So, I understand that, if (just assume) setTimeout returns a promise we can achieve the same implementation in the TestAsync by "await setTimeout()".

Comment: Correct. Anything returning a promise can be awaited upon. When marking a function as async, it will be internally adapted to return a promise, taking care to correctly chain any uses of await inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

the error is that you are not waiting for setTimeout to finish, you need to wrap it in a promise and await for it.

```js
function wait(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
class TestAsync {
    async f1(n) {
        await wait(1500);
        console.log("Async 1: " + n);
        return n;
    };

    async f2(n) {
        await wait(1000);
        console.log("Async 2: " + n);
        return n;
    };

    async f() {
        await this.f1(1)
        await this.f2(2);
    };
}

new TestAsync().f()
```